# Copy certain characters from a list to another on prolog

Tags: list, copy, prolog

So i have this code which copies everything from a list to another one. 
How should I modify it in order to copy, lets say the first two character.

```
$copy(L,R) :- 
    copy2(L,R).
copy2([X],[X]).
copy2([H|T1],[H|T2]) :-
    copy2(T1,T2).
```

example of what i want it to be: ?- copy([a,b,c,d,e,f],X,**2**). --> X = [a,b]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy lists just with unification:

```
?- [a,b,c,d,e] = List.
List = [a, b, c, d, e].

?- [a,b,c,d,e] = [V,W,X,Y,Z].
V = a,
W = b,
X = c,
Y = d,
Z = e.

?- [a,b,c,d,e] = [V,W|Rest].
V = a,
W = b,
Rest = [c, d, e].
```

A predicate like the one you describe, copying the first N elements of a list, can be defined thus:

```
first_n(List, N, Xs) :-
    length(Xs, N),
    append(Xs _, List).
```

Which works like so:

```
?- first_n([a,b,c,d,e], 2, X).
X = [a, b].
```

There are a bunch of different ways to write a similar predicate. The way I have defined `first_n/3`, it will fail if N is larger than the length of `List` (this was pointed to out by @false in the comments). One could instead write an analog of the common function [take](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:take), which will return `List` in its entirety in the event that `N` is greater than `List`'s length:

```
take_n(N, List, Taken) :-
    ( length(List, M),
      N > M
    ->
      Taken = List
    ;
      length(Taken, N),
      append(Taken, _, List)
    ).
```

---

*This answer was corrected (several times) under the guidance of @false's helpful criticism.*

Comment: Is this really take? Consider `take_n([], 5, T).`

Comment: @false thanks for your correction (albeit gnomic, as is your wont). I'm amending my answer.

Comment: It does: if `Taken = []` then `length(Taken, 1)` will fail.

Comment: If I run the query you give, I get this: `?- take_n([1], 1, []).
false.` Why is it irrelevant that `length(Taken, 1)` fails? When that fails, Prolog tries the other side of the disjunction, and if `Taken == []` and `List == [1]` then *obviousy* `Taken \= List`, so that will fail as well. What am I missing here?

Comment: **You** are right for my last case (which I will delete). I should have given the case: `take_n([1],0,[1])` which should fail, but succeeds!

Comment: I see! Thanks for working through that with me. I often miss these edge cases. You seem to have an excellent eye for them. Is it just through experience, or do you have a particular methodology for discovering them? I'll try to think up an elegant way to correct the meaning of the program (if it weren't for our conversation here, I'd probably just delete `take_n` from my answer at this point).

Comment: It's mostly routine. But an easy way (which I did not use in the first place) is to start with the most general query and look at the answers - at least in the mind. The 2nd alternative gave as answer: `Taken = List` for all `N` - so I devised a case where this should not be true.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That makes good, practical sense. Too often, I only think as far as achieving a specific goal, and then don't stop to think about the broader implications of a predicate in the most general case.  Hopefully I finally narrowed the definition down.